# Two targets for the same column datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables-1.10

I have a datatable with json ajax.

But, i need to pass for the same column two targets. How i do that?

```
            "columns": [
            { "data": "tpPedido" },
            { "data": "os" },
            { "data": "userMobile.nome" },
            { "data": "produto.nmProduto" },
            { "data": "status.NmStatus" },
            { "data": "produto.garantia.descricao" },
            { "data": "valor" },
            { "data": "valoradiantado" },
            { "data": "idPedidoAssistencia" },
            { "data": "idPedidoAssistencia" }
        ],
```

And the columndefs  i trying to do this:

```
{ "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return '<a onclick="relatorioAcerto('+data+')">R$: ' + parseFloat(data).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',').replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\,)/g, "$1." + '</a>');
            },  "targets": 6,9},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define directly in `columns` array. `render` function accept three parameters. The last parameter holds entire data object.

```
  "columns": [
        { "data": "tpPedido" },
        { "data": "os" },
        { "data": "userMobile.nome" },
        { "data": "produto.nmProduto" },
        { "data": "status.NmStatus" },
        { "data": "produto.garantia.descricao" },
        { 
               "data": null,
               "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="'+row.idPedidoAssistencia+'" >Click here</a>';
               }
        },
        { "data": "valoradiantado" },
        { "data": "idPedidoAssistencia" },
        { 
               "data": null,
               "render" : function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="'+row.idPedidoAssistencia+'" >Click here</a>';
               } 
         }
    ],
```